# SP.UI.ModalDialog Namespace or Reference

Tags: web-part, client-object-model, modal-dialog

Is there any server side reference for `SP.UI.ModalDialog`? 
What is the reference for `SP.UI.ModalDialog` for client side? How i reference this in webpart?

Comment: You can use JavaScript to call SP.UI.ModalDialog.*Method*()

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is refer to "sp.js" file provided by the sharepoint

if sharepoint : 2010:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" runat="server" Name="sp.js" 
    OnDemand="false" Localizable="false" LoadAfterUI="true"/>
```

or

```
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If Sharepoint 2013:

New way of attaching the modal dialogs:

```
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
```

Comment: Modal works with "SP.UI.Dialog.js"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if your code is in SharePoint site, there is no need of giving script refernce., because, sp.js will be already included in the Master Page.

Infact you can use this as below sample

```
function successHandler(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Created Successully", false);
```

}

Comment: SP.UI is not part of `sp.js` though..